# URL is not same as PHP $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox + Vagrant + CentOS 7.0 + PHP.

When i enter the page `http://192.168.33.10/public/index.php`:

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/public/index.php');
```

This should redirect to `public/public/index.php`, but I don't know why it redirects to `/vagrant/public/public/index.php`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Because the actual path to the root is not the same as your URL.

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339195/how-do-i-change-the-default-folder-for-vagrant-from-being-html

Comment: Part of the debugging process is learning what you're actually working with, so step 1 is to echo `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and see what it _actually_ is, because [it's not what you think it is](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and you need to verify this on your machine.

Comment: What Qirel says.  That variable is a host-machine file system location, not a web URL location.

Answer (score 1):

It's just wrong!
First of all you use header() in a wrong way

**correct:**

```
header('Location: URL');
```

And you use the wrong variable:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

returns the absolute local path on the machine.

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] would fit better, but remember addings http/https in front of it

**BUT:**

You don't need to add the current servername - Just add the path

```
header('Location: /public/index.php');
```

This will always redirect to HTTP(S)://YOURSERVER/public/index.php

And you can also use relative paths, just remove the trailing slash

Comment: Er, it's best practise for `header` Locations to give a FQDN. I know 99% of systems respect relative pathing but that can only   be assumed, not expected. It's better to give a FQDN.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location

Relative Path is in the specs...

Comment: my problem is URL is not same as PHP $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
url is /public but $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] show /vagrant/public.
header just is example.

Comment: Doesnt change my answer. Just set the correct path
otherwise change the document root of your vhost